# How to get rid of repeated Notification from Microsoft

Tags: notifications

How can I stop the following notification from appearing every time I launch my outdated version of MS EDGE that I am happy with while using Windows 7?

“Microsoft Edge Is no longer supported on this version of Windows.  Upgrade to Windows 10 or later to get regular feature and security updates from Microsoft Edge.  Learn more”

Comment: You won't be happy with a malware full OS, used for criminal endeavors, your identity stolen, etc. The notification you're complaining of is actually trying to save you from yourself. Obsolete, unsupported, unpatched, OSes shouldn't be used online, period.

Answer (score 2):

This should help :

- Open `regedit`
- Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft`
- Create a new sub-key named `Edge`
- In that key, create a DWORD named `SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning`
  and set it to `1`.

Source : [Suppress the unsupported OS warning](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning).

Comment: Has somebody tried this before downvoting ?

Comment: Hi Harry - I do not know - was not me.

Comment: @John: I didn't suspect you, mate. Probably the same person that left the comment on the post.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run IE.  Edge will may give you this message depending on the state of your Windows 7 operating system. - that is life. Try an old unsupported version of Chrome.  You may also wish to try Firefox as well. Firefox is not Chromium-based.

You can try suppressing the Edge message (may depend on the state of your Windows 7 machine).

See:  [Suppress Edge Warning](https://admx.help/?Category=EdgeChromium&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.Edge::SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning)

> Registry Hive HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE or HKEY_CURRENT_USER Registry
>
> Path  Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge Value
>
> Name  SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning Value
>
> Type   REG_DWORD
>
> Enabled Value  1
>
> Disabled Value    0

Otherwise, Windows 7 is long dead and out of support. Not even security patches.  To keep running it is to risk your security. Windows 7 is likely to attract viruses of all kind.

So heed the warning and upgrade to at least a version of Windows 10 still in support.

Comment: I'd only change this advice to use FireFox rather than Chrome, or a non-Google Chromium-based browser flavor. Chrome is adequate, but has too many clear and known issues with privacy and security.

Comment: Thank you . Advice taken and answer amended

Comment: @music2myear - Firefox 115 was the last version to support Windows 7.  Chromium also already dropped for Windows 7.

Comment: @John - It most certainly is possible to suppress this warning message. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1164907/how-to-block-microsoft-edge-is-no-longer-supported) is specific instructions for Edge.  Chrome would have it's own registry key.

Comment: My primary point was to upgrade. Nonetheless I added a suppression way to my answer.  You might retract your downvote @Ramhound